# Align inputs and button vertically and horizontaly

Tags: html, css

I try to align inputs and button vertically and horizontally on the page.

Usually css, provided below works nicely for block elements, but not for inputs.

Please see jsfiddle below:

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.input, .button {
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  
  <div class="inner">
  
    <input type="text" class="input">
    <input type="text" class="input">
    <button type="text" class="button">Button</button>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change CSS

```css
body,html{
height:100%;
margin:0;
}
.outer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  
  left: 50%;
  
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%)
  
}

.input, .button {
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  
  <div class="inner">
  
    <input type="text" class="input">
    <input type="text" class="input">
    <button type="text" class="button">Button</button>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I love how you used `transform: translate(-50%,-50%)` and learned something new! Thanks! Marked as accepted. I think you can omit `body, html` and `margin:0 auto` to simplify things, since those tags may have other styles.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way i used to do it.

```css
.outer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.inner {
  width:200px;
  margin: auto;
  height:20vh;
  padding-top:30vh;
}

.input, .button {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  
  <div class="inner">
  
    <input type="text" class="input">
    <input type="text" class="input">
    <button type="text" class="button">Button</button>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But this will not work. Try to Run code snippet then expand it to Full page